# How to list names one by one in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, css, angularjs-ng-repeat

**HTML**

```
<ul class="ul_nav">
            <li ng-repeat="teams in teamArray" 
                    style="-webkit-animation-delay: {{$index * 150}}ms">
              {{teams.team_name}}
      </li>
</ul>
```

Here I can list teams. But I need to display(list) teams one by one. How to give this effects. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eVZbXa5R9LmQcyLn2gzE?p=preview)

Comment: how actually you want the output, can you please show list demo here.. i did not get your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `$timeout` to get your animation to work when the page loads.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.teamArray = [{
      "team_name": "A"
    }, {
      "team_name": "B"
    }, {
      "team_name": "C"
    }];
  });
  
  $scope.change = function() {
    $scope.teamArray = [{
      "team_name": "D"
    }, {
      "team_name": "E"
    }, {
      "team_name": "F"
    }];
  };
});
```

```css
.stagger-demo.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  padding-left: 30px;
  transition: all ease 250ms;
}
.stagger-demo.ng-enter-stagger {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
}
.stagger-demo.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1.0;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-animate.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click="change()">Other Data</button>
  <ul class="ul_nav">
    <li class="stagger-demo" ng-repeat="teams in teamArray">
      {{teams.team_name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

---

Another option is outlined here:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5130

He notes that it is a "dirty hack".

Also mentioned here:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10536

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootElement) {
  $scope.teamArray = [{
    "team_name": "A"
  }, {
    "team_name": "B"
  }, {
    "team_name": "C"
  }];
  $rootElement.data("$$ngAnimateState").running = false;
});
```

```css
.stagger-demo.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  padding-left: 30px;
  transition: all ease 250ms;
}
.stagger-demo.ng-enter-stagger {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
}
.stagger-demo.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1.0;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-animate.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul class="ul_nav">
    <li class="stagger-demo" ng-repeat="teams in teamArray">
      {{teams.team_name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

//Try this use limitTo in ng-repeat

```
<ul class="ul_nav">
            <li ng-repeat="teams in teamArray | limitTo:noOfItemToDisplay">
              {{teams.team_name}}
      </li>
</ul>
```

//and in controller

```
$scope.noOfItemToDisplay=1;
```

//use setTimeout() to update noOfItemToDisplay as per time delay that you want. like

```
while($scope.noOfItemToDisplay <= $scope.teamArray.length){
    setTimeout(updateList(),2500);        
}

function updateList(){
     $scope.noOfItemToDisplay+=1;
}
```